Register open generic Serilog logger via factory
One can resolve a framework logger with category by idiomatic .NET code:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Foo
{
  private readonly ILogger<Foo> _logger;

  public Foo(ILogger<Foo> logger) =>
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}

With Serilog it's more complicated:
using Serilog;

public class Foo
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public Foo(ILogger logger) =>
    _logger = logger?.ForContext<Foo>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}

It's easy to forget the logger?.ForContext<Foo>() and it' a bit of a nuisance too.
I'd like to be able to do this:
using Serilog;

public class Foo
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public Foo(ILogger<T> logger) =>
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}

Unfortunately it's currently impossible to register an open generic type using a factory.
So any variation of this won't work:
// ILogger`T.cs
using Serilog;
public interface ILogger<T> : ILogger { }

// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddTransient(
  typeof(Serilog.ILogger<>), 
  sp => sp.GetRequiredService<Serilog.ILogger>().ForContext<>()
);

Is there some way to do this?
(Without reflection, as in a non-trivial system one expects a very large number of logger resolutions per second. And without the Serilog.Log static class, as I prefer an idiomatic .NET approach.)

It's _logger = loggerFactory?.Logger ??... acceptable?

If so, then you can make ILoggerFactory<T> face with ILogger Logger {get;} then implement it in LoggerFactory<T> which takes ILogger as constructor parameter and getter would return logger.ForContext<T>()... Then in Foo class you change constructor to accept ILoggerFactory<Foo>... Register dependency and call it done...

Second option is to implement ILogger<T> by proxing all calls to underling logger... In other words create generic wrapper around ILogger which takes ILogger as constructor parameter and store results of ForContext() in field and all calls are redirected there

I think you're overcomplicating things. There is a reason why logging in ASP.NET Core is hidden behind an abstraction level. Coming up with unnecessarily clever ways to create a generic Serilog logger is essentially recreating a wheel instead using known solutions: a MS built-in ILogger<T>.

One reason I can think of why you would stick to explicit Serilog logger usage is because you are using Serilog explicitly across application instead of MS ILogger. But that's a different problem and could be the root cause for this question. There is a NuGet package from Serilog that integrates Serilog with MS built-in ILogger. What's stopping you from using it?

@Selvin thanks for those ideas, but what I wanted to do was hide the "ForContext" and anything similar. The proxy is an interesting idea.

@Prolog thanks for that. I'm already using Serilog.AspNetCore which does that. The complication you've noted is because I'm trying NOT to use MEL, because Serilog's logger exposes very useful enrichment and timings operations which MEL does not. But converting one's thinking from one way to another leads to mistakes as I noted above, so I was trying to find a way to bring the two APIs closer together.

It is possible. You need to recreate what MS does with their built-in logger. We need a generic interface to keep the generic type parameter.
public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
{
}

An interface needs an implementation. This essentially is a wrapper over Serilog main logger.
public class SerilogCategoryLogger<TCategoryName> : ILogger<TCategoryName>
{
    private readonly ILogger categoryLogger;

    public SerilogCategoryLogger(ILogger logger)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(logger);

        categoryLogger = logger.ForContext<TCategoryName>();
    }

    public void Write(LogEvent logEvent) => categoryLogger.Write(logEvent);
}

And service registration bits:
services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(SerilogCategoryLogger<>));

Notice that this approach requires an already initialized Serilog logger instance. So usually it would look like shown below or standard UseSerilog() called on IHostBuilder in Program.cs.
services.AddLogging(b => b.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));

Make sure you use Serilog not MS namespace for logging, otherwise you'll end up with errors.
Simple console app demo showcasing the wrapper:
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception})")
            .CreateLogger();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(b => b.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));
        services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(SerilogCategoryLogger<>));
        services.AddTransient<TestService>();
        using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var testService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestService>();
        testService.DoWork();
    }
}

public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
{
}

public class SerilogCategoryLogger<TCategoryName> : ILogger<TCategoryName>
{
    private readonly ILogger categoryLogger;

    public SerilogCategoryLogger(ILogger logger)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(logger);

        categoryLogger = logger.ForContext<TCategoryName>();
    }

    public void Write(LogEvent logEvent) => categoryLogger.Write(logEvent);
}

public class SerilogTestService(ILogger<SerilogTestService> logger)
{
    public void DoWork() => logger.Information("It is working.");
}

Final note
In my personal opinion, I do not recommend this solution unless you have good reasons. As I stated before, there is a reason why logging in ASP.NET Core is done over a common and agreed-upon level of abstraction. Benefits from this abstracted architecture usually outweigh using an explicit logging provider approach, mostly because anyone familiar with the ASP.NET Core tech stack can walk into your source code and understand the logging parts.

Nice solution! As for the warning, sometimes it's a good idea to use Serilog/NLog instead of MEL, for the same reason some people use Autofac/StructureMap/etc. instead of the built-in container: it provides more functionality. For Serilog, e.g. custom enrichment, timings, auditing, etc. But for the general case I agree with you that MEL is good enough and simpler to use.

hmmm, I'm pretty sure I've mentioned about such solution in my comment...

Found related issue at the repo. Looks like we'll have native support for Serilog.ILogger<T> someday.
